# How to get results of shell command line by line in for sentese?

Tags: bash

I am learning shell script. And I want to check size of directories(and files). I made a sample script as

```
#!/bin/bash

for dir in $(du ".")
do
  echo "dir = $dir"
  read T_SIZE T_PATH <<< $dir
  echo "T_SIZE = $T_SIZE"
  echo "T_PATH = $T_PATH"
done
```

The structure of directories under current directory has only one directory, "a".

The results are

```
dir = 4
T_SIZE = 4
T_PATH = 
dir = ./a
T_SIZE = ./a
T_PATH = 
dir = 16
T_SIZE = 16
T_PATH = 
dir = .
T_SIZE = .
T_PATH =
```

It seems command "du" gives results word by word.
However, I expected command "du" gives results line by line and I expected the results of the script above are

```
dir = 4
T_SIZE = 4
T_PATH = ./a
dir = 16
T_SIZE = 16
T_PATH = .
```

Please tell me what was wrong or suggestion to me.

Thank you very much.

Comment: Indeed I didn't fully understand it. A while loop as John suggested would be the answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To read the output of a command, like `du`, line by line, try:

```
du . | while read size path
do
   echo "size=$size path=$path"
done
```

Or, if you are using a shell, such as bash, that supports process substitution:

```
while read size path
do
   echo "size=$size path=$path"
done < <(du ".")
```

There is a big difference between these two approaches.  In the first above, the `while` loop runs in a subshell and, thus, all its shell variable variables disappear after the subshell finishes.  In the latter code, the shell variables remain available after the `while` loop completes.

Answer (score 1):

You need to use a `while` loop to iterate line-by-line over the output of a command.

```
while read size dir; do
  echo "$dir is $size bytes"
done < <(du .)
```

Even this will fail in the rare, but legitimate, case of a directory name containing a new line. There is not much, though, you can do about that, short of using a version of `find` that can output null-delimited output in place of `du`.